# Why ML Workbench on Acumos is not enabled?

Tags: acumos

I have created an account on Acumos portal, i.e. at the official Acumos website. When I sign in and go to Design Studio, I find ML Workbench grayed and disabled, being impossible to launch it. What are the previous steps necessary to gain access to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datariel  The MLW is disabled on the official Acumos website to avoid people create plenty of projects, datapipeline and notebooks just for test most of the time. All these objects need ressources and we cannot manage them.

Comment: Perfect @Phil, so it will be available in my own Acumos instance, and the same for other resources like the on-boarding model page, I guess, from which the push_api argument must be taken, right?

Comment: Yes right, if you install CLIO instance MLWB is installed by default, but if you install Demeter instance, the MLWB is an option (called plugin in the z2a installer) so you have to check the documentation to know how to install this plugin. For both Demeter and Clio, on-boarding model page is installed by default